# Откуда взялся промежуток между двумя картинками в горизонтальном UIScrollView?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift4, uiscrollview

Не могу разобраться, откуда взялся промежуток между двумя картинками в горизонтальном UIScrollView, при его пролистывании?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
СкролВью автоматически листает картинки по таймеру, скролвью расположен на всплывающем окне, отображается окно по нажатию на кнопку. Ниже скрол с таймером

```
_ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        scrollImage = [UIImage(named: "123")!, UIImage(named: "456")!, UIImage(named: "sharing")!, UIImage(named: "smska")!]
        subView.image.delegate = self

        for i in 0..<scrollImage.count {

            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.image = scrollImage[i]
            //imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.subView.image.frame.width, height: self.subView.image.frame.height)

            subView.image.contentSize.width = subView.image.frame.width * CGFloat(scrollImage.count)
            subView.image.addSubview(imageView)
        }
```

// здесь функция вызываемая таймером

```
@objc func timerAction() {

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
    let page = subView.image.contentOffset.x / subView.image.frame.size.width
    subView.pageControl.currentPage = Int(page)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveLinear, animations: {
            self.subView.image.contentOffset.x += 300
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать констрейн который приравнивает ширину UIView к 300стам. Может причина в этом?

Comment: Убрал, расстояние примерно вдвое уменьшилось, но не ушло целиком. Все равно отображается не корректно((